# Advantages/disadvantages to using struct as a parameter while defining new API

Tags: ruby, api, parameters, struct

The APIs that I am writing are for a Ruby class that inherits from ActiveRecord. I am trying to write static methods to avoid leaking the ActiveRecord instance. All the APIs now need  tuple to uniquely identify a database row.

Is it a good idea to have APIs of the form:

API1(abc, def, ....)
API2(abc, def, ....)
and so on

or should I define a struct with  fields to help with future changes?

Any other ideas are greatly welcome!

Comment: Would appreciate design input as well. Is the idea of using a hash instead of individual parameters better or worse in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Using a struct would be strange in Ruby, a Hash would be normal:

```
def self.api1(options)
    # Look at options[:abc], options[:def], ...
end
```

And then it could be called using named arguments like this:

```
C.api1 :abc => 'abc', :def => '...'
```

Easy to extend, common Ruby practice, and easy to make certain parameters optional.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using a hash. In my case, these parameters are not really optional as they uniquely identify a database record.

Comment: @Smitten: you don't have to call them options and you can (and should) validate that everything you need is there. Using a hash is an easy way of handling long argument lists. You can go with a or al argument list but it will get unwieldy if there are more than a couple arguments. OTOH, Ruby will complain about the wrong number of arguments with simple positional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

To continue what mu is describing, a common Ruby idiom you'll see it to have a method set itself some default options and then merge into that hash the options that the method received. This way you can be sure that some minimum list of options always exist:

```
def self.api1(options={})
  default_options = { :foo => 'bar', :baz => nil }
  options = default_options.merge options
  # Now include your code and you can assume that options[:foo] and options[:bar] are there
end
```

This comes in handy when your method, for example, outputs the value of `:baz`. Now you don't need to check that it exists first, you can just output it knowing that it would always exist.